# Is it possible to hide user typed input in REXX program

Tags: rexx

I need to PULL a password that a user will type, but don't want the 
characters to display on the screen. Could you help me to achieve this in REXX.

Comment: Where is your REXX code running? ISPF? Windows? Linux? OS/2?  Which dialect of REXX are you using?  OOREXX?  Regina?

Comment: It will be running in ISPF, I am not using OOREXX or Regina. I am running this in z/OS.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are running in ISPF, you can define a panel to reside in the ISPPLIB concatenation with a password field that is non-display.

Answer (score 6):

As @cshneid, use an ISPF Panel (and place it in the ISPPLIB).
Here is an example panel containing a password field (see $ attribute) taken from [ISPF Manual](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.r12.f54dg00%2Fhhlp.htm).

```
)ATTR
  * TYPE(TEXT)   INTENS(HIGH) COLOR(WHITE) CAPS(OFF)
  # TYPE(TEXT)   INTENS(HIGH) COLOR(BLUE)  CAPS(OFF)
  @ TYPE(TEXT)   INTENS(LOW)  COLOR(BLUE)  HILITE(REVERSE)
  ? TYPE(TEXT)   INTENS(LOW)  COLOR(TURQ)  CAPS(OFF)
  _ TYPE(INPUT)  INTENS(HIGH) COLOR(YELLOW)
  $ TYPE(INPUT)  INTENS(NON)
  ø TYPE(OUTPUT) INTENS(LOW)  COLOR(TURQ)  CAPS(OFF)
)BODY
* --------------------------@EMPLOYEE RECORD*--------------------------
# SERIAL NO.*===>_SERNUM  +&rbl                                          %
#
#
#   NAME:?&LAST, &FIRST
#
#   ADDRESS:øADDR1                      + 
#           øADDR2                      + 
#           øADDR3                      + 
#           øADDR4                      + 
#
#   POSITION:øPOSIT                     + 
#
#   YEARS EXPERIENCE:øYRS+ 
#
#   SALARY:øSALARY +       # PASSWORD*===>$PSW   + 
#                              (Password is required for salary)
#
#
* Enter#END*command to terminate application.
#
)PROC
   VER(&SERNUM,NB,NUM)
   .ATTR(.CURSOR) = 'COLOR(RED) HILITE(BLINK)'
)END
```

Please note I do not have a mainframe available to check so the following so there may be  some syntax errors:

Rexx command to display a panel:

```
Address ispexec display panel(panelName)
```

If you need to add a DSN to the  ISPPLIB

```
"ispexec libdef ispplib dataset id(panel-dsn)"
```

---

## Background information

ISPF uses a series of files (ispplib, ispmlib, isptlib etc) to store the details it uses. You can add extra PDS (on a temporary basis) to ISPF using the **LIBDEF** function in a rexx/clist programs. Historically these PDS's where RECFM=FB and had a LRECL of 80. This has changed. You should check the attributes of the existing ispplib PDS's and use similar attributes.

To display a **panel** it needs to be stored in the ISPPLIB (or a PDS allocated to
ispplib using **LIBDEF**).

if you store the panel in pds my.panels(test) and allocate my.panels to ISPPLIB, the rexx is:

```
   /* rexx */
    address ispexec 'display panel(test)'
    say rc        /* show return code, will indicate possible errors */
```

if you use **LIBDEF** then the rexx is

```
  /* rexx */

    address ispexec "libdef ispplib dataset id(panel-dsn)" 
    say rc

    address ispexec 'display panel(test)'
    say rc        /* show return code, will indicate possible errors */
```

---

The [Edit Macro guide](http://publibz.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr_OS390/BOOKS/ISPZRS40/CCONTENTS?DT=20050711210710) has a list of services (and there return-codes)

If you allocate the panel to the panel library, you can also us the ispf test mode (ispf 7.1 ??? its been a while since I used the Mainframe) to test it

Comment: I am not able to see the panel while executing the above command.
Could guide me on how to view the panel

Comment: Are there any messages ???, also display the return code and look it up in the ISPF manual. Finally I have added some extra information at the end of my answer

Comment: Thanks Bruce and finally it is working now. Thanks for all your help:)